# How do I restart timer?

Tags: c, signals, system-calls

I use the following code to set an alarm.

```
struct itimerval timer;
struct sigaction sa;

sa.sa_handler = handler;
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND;
timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
timer.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, 0);
setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, 0);
```

How do I restart the timer after it has exited the handler function and went into the while loop below. Do I need to reinitialize everything or just call setittimer?

```
while(pause() == -1)
{   
    // goes in here after handler function.. what needs to go here to restart timer?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singe you use `SA_RESETHAND` you need to call both `sigaction` and `setitimer` again. I suggest you put it in a function so you don't have to write the code to start (or restart) the timer twice or more.

Comment: Would you recommend this function have all of the initialization properties or simply the sigaction and setittimer calls?

Comment: @Lucas All the initialization too.